# Nonlinear ODE $\dot{X}(t)X(t)=B$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-equations

I am learning ODE now.

we know for ODE:
$$\dot{X}(t)=A(t)X(t),X(t_0)=x_0$$
where $X\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times 1},A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$.

The solution has the following form:
$$X(t)=e^{\int_{t_0}^{t}A(s)ds}x_0$$
My question is for the following ODE:
$$\dot{X}(t)X(t)=A(t),X(t_0)=x_0$$
where $X\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n},A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$.

Do we have general experison? By the way, can we use this ODE to define $\log{A}$
?

Comment: How do you define $\dot{X}(t)X(t)$, I assume as a [vector direct product](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VectorDirectProduct.html), in order to comply with the dimensions of $A(t)$?

Comment: $\dot{X}(t)X(t)=[\dot{X_1}{X_1},\dot{X_2}{X_2},..,\dot{X_n}{X_n}]^T$

Comment: But that definition does not have the same dimension as $A(t)$, namely according to your definition $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$.

Comment: Oh. ...I got it.  I will correct something,thanks @fibonatic

Comment: We assume that $X\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$

Comment: Equations in spaces of matrices are complicated (and even impossible) to solve explicitly, mostly because the matrix product is not commutative. If you knew that $X(s) X(t) = X(t) X(s) \forall t, s$, then you could work something out, but in general you can't do much about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do **not** know that.  $X(t) = e^{\int_{t_0}^t A(s)\; ds} x_0$ is a solution to your first differential equation if the $A(s)$ all commute, but not otherwise.  What you need in general is a "[time-ordered exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_exponential)".

A similar difficulty applies to your second equation.  **If**  $X(t)$ and $\dot{X}(t)$ commute, then $Y(t) = X(t)^2$ satisfies $\dot{Y}(t) =  2 \dot{X(t)} X(t) = 2 A(t)$, so 
$X(t)$ is a square root of $Y(t) = Y(0) + 2 \int_0^t A(s)\; ds$.  But if they don't commute, $\dot{Y}(t) = \dot{X(t)} X(t) + X(t) \dot{X(t)}$, and we don't know what to do with the second term.